# Javascript Alert not displaying

Tags: javascript, html

I am working from the book "Simply JavaScript" and there is an example on pages 68-69 that I cannot get to run. I have copied it from the book and I am working with a fellow student. I think there must be a coding error in the example and was hoping someone could look it over real quick and give us some guidance.

From what I understand the script should cause an alert box to pop up and display the node name (which according to the book should just be `a`)

Here is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>
Stupid Title
</title>
</head>

<body>

 <h1>
 Sniper (1998)
 </h1>

 <p> 
 In this cinema masterpiece
 <a id ="berenger" href="name/nm0000297/">tom Berenger</a> plays a us soldier working    in the Panamanian Jungle.
 </p>
</body>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
alert("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAHH");

var target = document.getElementById("berenger");
if (target != null)
    alert(target.nodeName);
```

This is my second week of javascript class so I'm pretty new with it.

Comment: i think you should try to figure out the problem since this is homework, why dont you look at the path to your js file

Comment: I've created a fiddle from your code, and it works as I understand it should: http://jsfiddle.net/d5w6j/

Comment: @MattStone I've updated your fiddle to actually match the question - http://jsfiddle.net/d5w6j/1/

Comment: @MattStone. The DOM man,  the DOM...

Comment: Ah yup, missed that it was external JS. JSFiddle wraps your JS in an onReady(), masking the real issue.

Comment: @MattStone Only by default. Check the left sidebar in my modification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DOM isn't ready at this point:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Move that line to the end of `<body>`

[Read about those kind of issues in this docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thank you, That did fix it. Is that a common thing? The reason why I ask is because so far the book has showed to put the code at the top (where I had it) I'm just wondering for future projects should I place the code at the bottom? Thanks again!

Comment: The proper thing is to put your code in a function and invoke it using `<body onload="yourfunction()">`. This ensures that it won't run until the DOM has completed loading.

Comment: @JeremyB. It's more complicated question than you think... There are people who prefer this way and people who prefer the other way. google it a bit.

Comment: @Barmar. No, it's not... this way you wait for the load event,  not the DOM ready event. read the docs in my answer please.

Comment: @Barmar: That waits for all resources to load. It'll work, but usually you want the code to run once the DOM itself is done loading.

Comment: That's jQuery, not vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar. The docs in jQuery site, so? the answer has nothing to do with jQuery. The fact someone might not using jQuery doesn't mean he should use the `onload` event for DOM manipulations...

Comment: I don't see anything in that jQuery documentation that says why you shouldn't use `onload` or suggests an alternative. What's the proper way to make sure your code doesn't run before the DOM is ready if you don't use `jQuery.ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar, Implement it by yourself, or use the DOM ready event that exists in some browsers, or put the `<script>` at the end of the `<body>` tag. There a lot better solutions even if you're not using jQuery than using the `onload` event. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not display it correctly because the JavaScript will load before the entire code fully load because of inside the head tag. It may cause errors because of the time that JS loaded elements are not available.

So, leave it under the body tag to use it whenever it wants.

Then it will display correctly.

Thank you.